# HTMLElement is not defined - Nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

All I'm trying to do at this point is get the project to run.

I run `tns run android`

The application builds, but as it starts the app and throws an error

> ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined

So this all started when I was trying to bring in the new nativescript theme core (2.2.0). I followed the guide they have posted in several places. Everything looked good. Then I ran `tns run android` and got the ***HTMLElement is not defined*** error for the first time.

- I've blown away the node_modules and platform folder
- npm rebuild
- tns install
- I've uninstalled nativescript-cli & cleared npm cache and re-installed (As mentioned here: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-project-pbxproj/7336)

I then decided to start again proceed to start with a clean project. Following the steps here: https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/

And when I run `tns run android` I still get the same ***HTMLElement is not defined*** error, even when I didn't modify the template at all.

I don't know if this is a bug or if I'm doing something horribly wrong

> tns --version 6.1.2
>
> node -v 12.10.0
>
> npm -v 6.10.3

So I am now getting this error no matter what I do now...

Code wise like I said I am getting this error with a clean pull of this template repo: https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template

Here is the Stack.

```
User-MacBook-Pro:hello-world user$ tns run android
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
Bundling application for entryPath ./main...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /Users/scottbaron/Mos-Commodo/social-platform/peak-app/peak-matching/node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/backend.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
Hash: d11e779b2f173a00da85
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 13195ms
Built at: 11/02/2019 10:57:09 AM
                             Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
assets/images/NativeScript-Vue.png   8.22 KiB           [emitted]  
                         bundle.js   84.3 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                      package.json  165 bytes           [emitted]  
                        runtime.js   71.4 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
               tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]  
                         vendor.js   9.45 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[./ sync ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$] . sync nonrecursive ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$ 175 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./ sync recursive (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$] . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$ 204 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.scss] 18.5 KiB {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./main.js] 1.96 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 146 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./store.js] 142 bytes {bundle} [built]
    + 208 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Project successfully prepared (android)
Building project...
Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from /Users/scottbaron/Mos-Commodo/social-platform/peak-app/peak-matching/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
         + using andorid X library androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/scottbaron/Mos-Commodo/social-platform/peak-app/peak-matching/node_modules/nativescript-socketio/platforms/android/fancylogger-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: /Users/scottbaron/Mos-Commodo/social-platform/peak-app/peak-matching/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar
Project successfully built.
The build result is located at: /Users/scottbaron/Mos-Commodo/social-platform/peak-app/peak-matching/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Installing on device 89EY06CQP...
Successfully installed on device with identifier '89EY06CQP'.
Restarting application on device 89EY06CQP...
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
System.err: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
System.err: File: "file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:517:28
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'handleCopy', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:517:28
System.err:     Frame: function:'clone', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:637:11
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:199:24
System.err:     Frame: function:'on', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:145:11
System.err:     Frame: function:'emit', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:179:17
System.err:     Frame: function:'devtoolPlugin', file:'file:///node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js:54:14
System.err:     Frame: function:'Store', file:'file:///node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js:356:4
System.err:     Frame: function:'./store.js', file:'file:///app/store.js:6:15
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///app/main.js:1:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.js', file:'file:///data/data/com.moscommodo.peak/files/app/bundle.js', line: 339, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'webpackJsonpCallback', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.moscommodo.peak/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2, column: 57
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: 
System.err: 
System.err: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
System.err: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
System.err: File: "file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:517:28
System.err: 
System.err: StackTrace: 
System.err:     Frame: function:'handleCopy', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:517:28
System.err:     Frame: function:'clone', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:637:11
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:199:24
System.err:     Frame: function:'on', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:145:11
System.err:     Frame: function:'emit', file:'file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:179:17
System.err:     Frame: function:'devtoolPlugin', file:'file:///node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js:54:14
System.err:     Frame: function:'Store', file:'file:///node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js:356:4
System.err:     Frame: function:'./store.js', file:'file:///app/store.js:6:15
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'fn', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:120:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///app/main.js:1:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'./main.js', file:'file:///data/data/com.moscommodo.peak/files/app/bundle.js', line: 339, column: 30
System.err:     Frame: function:'__webpack_require__', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:750:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'checkDeferredModules', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:43:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'webpackJsonpCallback', file:'file:///app/webpack/bootstrap:30:0
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/com.moscommodo.peak/files/app/bundle.js', line: 2, column: 57
System.err:     Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
System.err: 
System.err: 
System.err: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6465)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Error calling module function 
System.err: ReferenceError: HTMLElement is not defined
System.err: File: "file:///node_modules/@vue/devtools/build/hook.js:517:28
System.err:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution that @sidheart pointed out works but it will not let you observe the store. The error is triggered because NativeScript does not have a DOM and therefore has no types for `HTMLElement`. A temporary solution is to add the line below to the object defined by `new webpack.DefinePlugin({})` in the file `webpack.config.js`:

```js
HTMLElement: function() {
 return false;
},
```

so that the full object looks like this:

```js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'global.TNS_WEBPACK': 'true',
  TNS_ENV: JSON.stringify(mode),
  process: 'global.process',
  HTMLElement: function() {
    return false;
  },
}),
```

Thanks to Brandon Gohsman for showing this solution in [his article](https://medium.com/@bgohsman_47507/nativescript-vue-with-vuex-and-vue-devtools-no-really-fe860e802d10).

Comment: thanks for the article. kinda stuck with this problem!

Answer (score 17):

I found the solution, update your `main.js` file

```
import store from './store' // <= this should be before VueDevtools 
import VueDevtools from 'nativescript-vue-devtools';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked after updating tns-core-modules to 6.2.0 and above error popped up.

Comment: This should be the approved answer. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it actually stops vue-devtools from seeing my store complete. Not the right answer @mojoblanco be more polite next time.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a project using:

```
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>
```

Don't install vue-devtools. I think it has something to do with vue-devtools trying to access the DOM which doesn't exist in Nativescript.

Comment: I don't know why it worked with devtools before.... But you are right that was the issue